# Jquery $(window).scrollTop(); method is scrolling to the particular location of the page and then scorlling again ot the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

*My Requirement:**

**when the user click the particular HTML Anchor Tag ,then the page is scorlling to the particular location on the page.**

**My Logic:**

for Scorlling to the particular location of the page ,I have used the Jquery $(window).scrollTop(); Method.

**My Issue:**

**when the User clicks the Anchor Tag(Got Questions?) in the header section of my webpage and then page scrolling to the quick enquiry portion of my page. after that it again scorlling to the top of the page.**

It want to stop at the quick enquiry section itself it must not again scorll to the top of the page.

**My CODE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function moveToBottom()
     {
      alert("before scorlling");
      $(window).scrollTop(1042); 
      $('.wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required').focus();
     alert("after scorlling");
     }
</script>
```

could anyone help me to find the solution this page scrolling .thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".customFooterMenu").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

I guess in your case you want to scroll to this class (customFooterMenu)

If the above method does not work try assigning an id to the div you want to scroll to and then use that id instead of customFooterMenu .

Answer (score 1):

how about use

```html
$(document).scrollTop(1042);
```

Comment: HI Stack Exachange Community User, If I use the $(document).scrolltop(1042); is aslo not scorlling .

Comment: @User395 you want to make move them with animation?

Comment: Hi Andrew,yes i need like that only,could you please help me to find solution.